# How do I plot box plots in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    Index (X1)  Index (X2)  Index (X3)
0   5.882343    9.564568    9.977265
1   5.669850    9.513452    9.581796
2   5.456141    9.280659    8.393673
3   3.874471    9.261816    8.313863
4   3.640098    7.667820    7.935063
5   3.559814    7.623439    6.713257
6   3.483627    7.584502    6.687415
7   3.319808    7.558787    6.101812
 ......
```

I want to make a 3 box plots on the same plot for these three columns. Moreover, the column lengths are not the same.

If I do this:

```
df.boxplot(by=['Index (X1)', 'Index (X2)', 'Index (X3)'])
```

I get this error:

> TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Comment: I tried the suggested code on this link, and it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, simply `df.boxplot()` works. I'm assuming you mean that if your column lengths aren't the same, you have some `NaN` values in your columns.

If your `df` has more columns, but you only want those three columns, try:

```
df[['Index (X1)', 'Index (X2)', 'Index (X3)']].boxplot()
# or
df.boxplot(column=['Index (X1)', 'Index (X2)', 'Index (X3)'])
```

Both result in the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - but I am still getting the error

Comment: Try *restarting python* and starting with `import matplotlib;
matplotlib.use('Agg')` (as in the link) **before** you do anything else?

Comment: Yes, did that :(

Comment: Can you plot anything at all? Like, does `plt.plot([1,2,3])` work?